# GIMP Python - Fill Path/Vector with color

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

I am trying to develop a script that i can run on opened SVG files. I want to iterate over all paths and fill the path with an arbitrary color ( I will be replacing this part of the code later). The first stage of this is just iterating over the paths, and I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. My code is below - why am I not seeing any paths being iterated over?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gimpfu import *

def plugin_main(image, layer, path):
    vectors_count, vectors = pdb.gimp_image_get_vectors(image)
    for n in vectors:
        pdb.gimp_image_select_item(image,CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE,n)
        foreground = pdb.gimp_context_get_foreground()
        pdb.gimp_edit_fill(image.layers[0], foreground)

register(
    "create_polygon_art",
    "Fills all the paths with the average color within path",
    "Fills all the paths with the average color within path",
    "Bryton Pilling",
    "Bryton Pilling",
    "2018",
    "<Image>/Filters/Fill all paths with average color",
    "RGB*, GRAY*",
    [],
    [],
    plugin_main
)

main()
```

I have also tried a number of different approaches I have found by googling, including using something simpler for the iteration like:

```
for v in gimp.Vectors
```

But no matter what I try I cannot seem to get evidence of an iteration over the paths.

I am using gimp 2.10.6 on Windows 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a trap... `pdb.gimp_image_get_vectors(image)` returns a list of integer ID for the paths, but the later calls require a `gimp.Vectors` object.

`image.vectors` is indeed a list of `gimp.Vectors` and you can iterate all the paths with

```
for vector in image.vectors:
```

More problems:

- You declare two args in register() but have three in your function. In practice you don't need the path argument, since you aere going to iterate them all anyway.
- The layer argument of your function is the active layer when the plugin is called, and is normally the one you want to paint
- `gimp-edit-fill` takes a color source and not a color. When you go further with your code you will have to set the foreground color, and push/pop the context
- `CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE` isn't a valid Python symbol, in Python you should use `CHANNEL_OP_REPLACE` (with underscores)

Two collections of  python scripts [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) and [there](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/).

If you are under Windows, some hints to debug your scripts [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Debugging-python-fu-scripts-in-Windows)

Your code with fixes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gimpfu import *

def plugin_main(image, layer):
    for p in image.vectors:
        pdb.gimp_image_select_item(image,CHANNEL_OP_REPLACE,p)
        pdb.gimp_edit_fill(layer, FOREGROUND_FILL)

register(
    "create_polygon_art",
    "Fills all the paths with the average color within path",
    "Fills all the paths with the average color within path",
    "Bryton Pilling",
    "Bryton Pilling",
    "2018",
    "<Image>/Test/Fill all paths with average color",
    "RGB*, GRAY*",
    [],
    [],
    plugin_main
)

main()
```

You can make you code more user-friendly by painting "strokes" (so you have one path with several strokes). If you want individual selections on strokes, you can copy them to a temporary path. Code for this can be found in some scripts in the collections above.

Comment: Thank you! I discovered the CHANNEL_OP_REPLACE needing underscores caused the script to not work, fixing this meant the script ran. The other points mentioned have been very helpful, thank you.